# Screen.width/Screen.TwipsperpixelX -different value for same

Tags: vb.net, screen, screen-resolution

I have VB Application which on loading changes the resolution of the system from 1280*1024 to 1024*768 . When I stop the application it restores the resolution to normal resolution which is defined as `NormalRes = Screen.Width / Screen.TwipsPerPixelX`. But when I do it for the second  time simultaneously it did not restored the resolution.

I checked the code and the resolution returned was 1024(horizontal=1280)*1024, hence it could not change resolution and stayed to 1024*768.

What bugs me is that the when the normal resolution is defined as `Screen.Width/Screen.TwipsPerPixelX`.

why is that it is giving different value (instead of 1280 it is giving 1024). Is it because when I changing the resolution first time its value changes?
Under what circumstances the value of the can have different values? ?

Seeking your help,
Satish kumar

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to recalculate the screen resolution, why don't you save the resolution before you changed it and then restore the old one when your application is being closed.

Example:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim oldSize As Size

    Public Sub Form_Load() Handles Form1.Load
        oldSize = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size
    End Sub

    Public Sub Form_Closed() Handles Form1.Closed
        SetScreenResolution(oldSize)
    End Sub

    Public Sub SetScreenResolution(size As Size)
        ' write your code to change the screen size here
    End Sub
End Class
```